# how can i apply correct watermarking by replacing a specific bit?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an RGB image on which i should apply watermarking.I extracted the red channel and i'm going  to embed at 6th bit .here is my code,understanding that i should use a grayscale image to get the desired result:

```
img1 = ycbcr2rgb(cat(3, y, cb, cr));
figure;

imshow(img1);
bit=6; 

figure(1);
imshow(img1); 
img2=rgb2ycbcr(img1);
rchannel=img2(:,:,1);
gchannel=img2(:,:,2);
bchannel=img2(:,:,3);
[row,col]=size(rchannel);
area=row*col;
i=1;
j=1;
k=1; 
water_img=imread('ft.jpg');
[w1,w2] = size(water_img);
figure;imshow(water_img);
wm=dec2bin(water_img);
Wlength=w1*w2*8;  %
host=dec2bin(img2);
cnt=0; 
while i < area
        cnt=cnt+1;
        if cnt>Wlength
            break;
        end 
        host(i,bit)=wm(j,k);
        k=k+1;
        if k>8
            k=1;
            j=j+1;
        end
       i=i+1;
 end
   key1=w1;
   key2=w2;

final=bin2dec(host);
final=reshape(final,row,col);
img1(1:row,1:col)=final(1:row,1:col);
figure;
imshow(img1);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
    Error in ==> watler at 170
    final=reshape(final,row,col);
```

can you please help me?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is specifically this statement: `host=dec2bin(img2);`.  `img2` is the YCbCr converted image, which means it is a **3D matrix**.  You said you wanted to extract the red channel and work on that, so what you should have done was this instead:

```
host = dec2bin(rchannel);
```

---

However, I'm going to suggest a completely different way of setting your 6th bit.  Use [`bitset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitset.html) instead.  Specifically, you'll want to use this definition:

```
C = bitset(A, BIT, V);
```

`A` would be the matrix that you want to set the bits in, `BIT` would be the bit position of each number  in `A` that you want to focus on and `V` is a matrix of the same size as `A` where any values that are non-zero will set the bit of the corresponding value in `A` specified in `BIT` to be 1, and 0 otherwise.   For example, supposing I had a matrix of zeros like so:

```
A = uint8(zeros(5,5))

A =

    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0
```

It is important to note that this is an **integer** type array (specifically `uint8`) or bit setting won't work in the way you intended.  Now, supposing I Had this array:

```
V =

     0     1     0     1     0
     1     0     0     1     1
     0     1     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0     1
     0     1     0     0     1
```

If I wanted to try and set the 6th bit using this array, this is what we get:

```
D = bitset(A, 6, V)

D =

    0   32    0   32    0
   32    0    0   32   32
    0   32    0   32    0
   32   32   32    0   32
    0   32    0    0   32
```

As such, for any values of `V` that are non-zero, we set the 6th bit to be 1, and those numbers get changed from 0 to 32 because if we change the 6th bit for a number that is `uint8` that is initially all zero, we transition from `00000000` to `00100000`, which is 32 in `uint8`.  Therefore, what I would recommend you do is specify a matrix `V` in the same fashion as above, which is the same size as that of `A` (the matrix you want to modify), then specify the bit you want to modify (6 in your case), then simply use `bitset`.  I think it'll be easier, and you don't have to go through all of those nasty loops (BTW, your code doesn't really make much sense.  I don't understand what's going on... no offense!)